# How can the client side validation be disabled in the python code generated from OpenAPI 3.x spec

Tags: python-3.x, swagger-codegen, openapi-generator

I have an application, which needs to be tested using in-house developed python automation. Originally, the application was developed using Swagger 2.x spec. Now it is migrated to use Open API 3.x

When it was on Swagger 2.x spec, I used to use swagger-codegen-cli-2.4.21.jar to generate the python client libraries, which we eventually consumed to write our automation. With the 2.4.21 jar we could disable the client side validation (configuration.py)

But after moving to OpenAPI 3.x, I am not able to use 2.4.21 jar because its not supported. So I used 3.0.36 jar to generate the python client libraries. But this doesn't have the option to disable the client side validation (in configuration.py). This is actually creating lot of problems because we are getting ValueErrors during GET calls.

I see that there are some discussions happened on the same, but none of them are conclusive enough that it is actually fixed in 3.x

https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/pull/4137

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/5530

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/pull/9717

So I need help to understand whether this is still a open issue (or) it is fixed in some 3.x release..? If its not fixed yet, is there a workaround to overcome this issue..?

As of now, we are commenting all the ValueErrors to get around the issue, but this is not recommended because we lose the validation capability during POST calls.

Answer (score 0):

On `python-nextgen` (latest Python generator) it is not implemented (you can indicate which type of validation can be skipped using  `disabled_client_side_validations` when creating the `configuration` object, maybe works for you?).

The `configuration` object also includes a property `client_side_validation` which seems to be intended for this purpose but at the moment there is no implementation.

The only option at the moment is to keep it or remove it for all operations.

Comment: Are you talking about openapi generator..? I could see self.client_side_validation in configuration.py but as you mentioned its not being used anywhere in the models. I did not understand the part where you mentioned "using disabled_client_side_validations". Can you please elaborate a bit more on that please (may be with an example)..?

Comment: This parameter     https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/0cf5ed619dbe61058a1ea4cdc68fe2be42777757/samples/openapi3/client/petstore/python-nextgen/petstore_api/configuration.py#L58

Comment: Forget this, I have just seen it has been removed https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/pull/14308

Answer (score 0):

I used the OpenAPI Generator 7.1.0 to create Python code. Now for every API endpoint there are 3 different methods available. Let us take for example the endpoint method auth_login_post. Now there would also be the endpoint methods auth_login_post_without_preload_content and auth_login_post_with_http_info.

Overview example:

- auth_login_post
- auth_login_post[_without_preload_content]
- auth_login_post[_with_http_info]

The response of auth_login_post contains mainly the validated response payload.
The response of auth_login_post_with_http_info is nearly the same as auth_login_post, but adds HTTP information like response headers and response status.

But if you would rather not have the response JSON validated, you would take auth_login_post_without_preload_content. In this case, the JSON payload of the response is not validated and is given to you as Python byte string.